# android expandlistview arrow

Tags: android

I know how to make an expandedlistview, but I don't know what should i use to see the arrow down and up , how please ?

like when i open a group the arrow becomes down and when i close it , the arrow becomes up

#### Main xml

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ExpandableListView

    android:id="@+id/ExpList"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:groupIndicator="@null" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Group xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### child xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChild"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove this line from your xml code `android:groupIndicator="@null"`